# change bid when you are below specific website

Tags: google-ads-api

is there a script way to increase my Bid for one keyword when i'm below specific website for that keyword. Can you change your bid when you are below specific website? I'm trying to advertise my dad's website and i need to change my bid every 5 min to stay first ,because there is one website that's always above me how is that possible? I'm noob to google adwords, but i have money to spent i just need to know if there is way to set automatic rules or script that will make me first no matter the price.

Comment: It´s possible to set rules to controle the position of the add. You find a detailed article here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2472779?hl=en
You could also increase your bid dramaticly, cause you don´t pay the price you set, you pay the price to get a Adscore, same as your competitor +1cent. Her you see a article how this works https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6297?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with portfolio bidding in Google AdWords and choosing your optimization for outranking share but this is a really bad idea. Don't go for first position if you don't know which metrics you should check to judge performance.

Comment: Thank you Dimitris ,won't sped more money until i learn more about Google AdWords and how it work's.